# mIRC code alteration not working as planned

Tags: mirc

I've been trying to edit some code I've found for a group of mine, but I've been riddled with some bugs, mainly with the text now showing correctly

```
on *:start:{
  hmake uno 50
  if ($isfile(uno.dat)) hload uno uno.dat
}
on *:exit: hsave uno uno.dat
on *:nick:{
  var %i = $hget(0), %c
  while (%i) {
    if ($newnick ison $hget(%i)) {
      %c = $v2
      break
    }
    dec %i
  }
  if ($hget(%c,$nick)) {
    hadd %c $newnick $v1
    hadd %c $hfind(%c,$nick).data $newnick
  }
}
on *:quit:{
  var %i = $hget(0), %c
  while (%i) {
    if ($me ison $hget(%i)) && ($hget($hget(%i),$nick)) remplayer %c $nick $nick has been removed from the current game.
    dec %i
  }
}
on *:part:#:{
  if (!$hget(#)) return
  if ($hget(#,$nick)) remplayer # $nick $nick was removed from the current game.
  elseif ($nick == $me) hfree #
}
on *:kick:#:{
  if (!$hget(#)) return
  if ($hget(#,$nick)) remplayer # $nick $nick was removed from the current game.
  elseif ($nick == $me) hfree #
}
on $*:text:/^[@!.](uno)?score/Si:#:{
  var %u = $iif($2,$2,$nick)
  $iif($left($1,1) == @,msg #,notice $nick) %u has $bytes($iif($hget(uno,%u),$v1,0),b) wins.
}
on $*:text:/^[@!.](uno)?top10$/Si:#:{
  var %x, %i = $hget(uno,0).item, %o
  while (%i) {
    %x = $instok(%x,$hget(uno,$hget(uno,%i).item),0,32)
    dec %i
  }
  %x = $sorttok(%x,32,nr)
  %i = 1
  while (%i <= 10) {
    if (!$hget(uno,%i).item) break
    %o = $addtok(%o,$ord(%i) $+ : $hfind(uno,$gettok(%x,%i,32),$calc($findtok(%o,$gettok(%x,%i,32),0,32) +1)).data - $bytes($gettok(%x,%i,32),b) |,32)
    inc %i
  }
  $iif($left($1,1) == @,msg #,notice $nick) $left(%o,-1)
}
on $*:text:/^[@!.]uno$/Si:#:{
  if ($hget(#,players)) notice $nick There is already a PokéUNO game in progress in # $+ .
  else {
    if ($hget(#)) hfree #
    hmake #
    hadd # p1 $nick
    hadd # $nick $cards(7)
    hinc # players
    msg # $nick has started Poké3U04N12O v1.0 by BrAndo and AuroVee. Type !join to join the game.
    notice $nick Type !deal to start the game.
  }
}
on $*:text:/^[@!.]?join$/Si:#:{
  if (!$hget(#,p1)) return
  elseif ($hget(#,$nick)) notice $nick You are already playing!
  else {
    hinc # players
    hadd # p $+ $hget(#,players) $nick
    hadd # $nick $cards(7)
    msg # $nick will be player $hget(#,players) $+ .
  }
}
on $*:text:/^[@!.](deal|start( ?game)?|play|begin)$/Si:#:{
  if (!$hget(#,p1)) return
  elseif (!$hget(#,$nick)) notice $nick You aren't in this game.
  elseif ($hget(#,turn)) notice $nick The game has already started.
  elseif ($nick != $hget(#,p1)) msg # Only $v2 can start the game.
  elseif ($hget(#,players) !> 1) msg # You need atleast two people to play.
  else {
    var %c = 01
    while (01* iswm %c) %c = $cards(1)
    hadd # top %c
    hadd # turn 1
    hadd # rev $true
    msg # $hget(#,p1) $+ 's turn.
    msg # Top card: $hget(#,top)
    notice $nick Your cards: $hget(#,$nick)
  }
}
on $*:text:/^[@!.](endgame|uno(stop|end))$/Si:#:{
  if (!$hget(#,p1)) return
  elseif ($nick != $hget(#,p1)) msg # Only $v2 can end the game.
  else {
    hfree #
    msg # Game ended by $nick $+ .
  }
}
on $*:text:/^[@!.]quit$/Si:#:{
  if (!$hget(#,p1)) return
  elseif (!$hget(#,$nick)) notice $nick You aren't in this game.
  else remplayer # $nick $nick has left the game.
}
on $*:text:/^[@!.]kickplayer (.+)$/Si:#:{
  if (!$hget(#,p1)) return
  elseif ($nick != $hget(#,p1)) msg # Only $v1 can kick people from the game.
  elseif (!$hget(#,$regml(1))) msg # $regml(1) is not in this game.
  else remplayer # $regml(1) $regml(1) has been kicked from the game by $nick $+ .
}
on $*:text:/^[@!.](show)?(hand|cards?)$/Si:#:{
  if (!$hget(#,p1)) return
  elseif (!$hget(#,$nick)) notice $nick You aren't in this game.
  else notice $nick Your cards: $hget(#,$nick)
}
on $*:text:/^[@!.](uno)?count$/Si:#:{
  if (!$hget(#,p1)) return
  else {
    $iif($left($1,1) == @,msg #,notice $nick) Current score: $regsubex($str(.,$hget(#,players)),/./g,$+($hget(#,p\n),:,$chr(32),$numtok($hget(#,$hget(#,p\n)),32),$chr(32))) 
    $iif($left($1,1) == @,msg #,notice $nick) Its $hget(#,p $+ $hget(#,turn)) $+ 's turn.
  }
}
on $*:text:/^[@!.]topcard$/Si:#:{
  if (!$hget(#,p1)) return
  msg # Top card: $hget(#,top)
}
on $*:text:/^[@!.]draw ?(card)?$/Si:#:{
  if (!$hget(#,p1)) return
  elseif (!$hget(#,$nick)) notice $nick You aren't in this game.
  elseif ($hget(#,p $+ $hget(#,turn)) != $nick) notice $nick It is not your turn.
  else {
    var %c = $cards(1)
    hadd # $nick $instok($hget(#,$nick),%c,0,32)
    notice $nick You drew: %c
    hadd # pass $nick
  }
}
on $*:text:/^[@!.]pass$/Si:#:{
  if (!$hget(#,p1)) return
  elseif (!$hget(#,$nick)) notice $nick You aren't in this game.
  elseif ($hget(#,p $+ $hget(#,turn)) != $nick) notice $nick It is not your turn.
  elseif ($hget(#,pass) != $nick) notice $nick You have to draw once first.
  else {
    nextturn
    var %nnick = $hget(#,p $+ $hget(#,turn))
    msg # %nnick $+ 's turn
    msg # Top card: $hget(#,top)
    notice %nnick Your cards: $hget(#,%nnick)
    hdel # pass
  }
}
on $*:text:/^[@!.]play/Si:#:{
  if (!$hget(#,p1)) return
  elseif (!$hget(#,$nick)) notice $nick You aren't in this game.
  elseif ($hget(#,p $+ $hget(#,turn)) != $nick) notice $nick It is not your turn.
  elseif (!$iscard($2-)) notice $nick Syntax: !play <color> <card> or !play WD4/W <color>
  elseif (!$hascard($2-,$nick)) notice $nick You don't have that card.
  else {
    noop $regex($iscard($2-),/^\x03(\d{2})(\[.+?\])$/)
    var %co = $regml(1), %c = $regml(2)
    if (%co isin $hget(#,top)) || (%c == $strip($hget(#,top))) || (%c == [*]) {
      delcard $nick $2-
      hadd # top $iscard($2-)
      if (%c == [D2]) {
        nextturn
        var %snick = $hget(#,p $+ $hget(#,turn)), %nnick, %msg
        hadd # %snick $instok($hget(#,%snick),$cards(2),0,32)
        nextturn
        %nnick = $hget(#,p $+ $hget(#,turn))
        if (%co == 12) {
          %msg = %snick is hit by Hydro Pump $+ $chr(44) and draws 2! %nnick $+ 's turn.
        }
        else if (%co == 09) {
          %msg = %snick is hit by Seed Flare $+ $chr(44) and draws 2! %nnick $+ 's turn.
        }
        else if (%co == 08) {
          %msg = %snick is hit by Thunder $+ $chr(44) and draws 2! %nnick $+ 's turn.
        }
        else {
          %msg = %snick is hit by Fire Blast $+ $chr(44) and draws 2! %nnick $+ 's turn.
        }
      }
      elseif (%c == [S]) {
        nextturn
        var %snick = $hget(#,p $+ $hget(#,turn)), %nnick, %msg
        nextturn
        %nnick = $hget(#,p $+ $hget(#,turn))
        %if (%co == 12) {
          %msg = %snick is hit by Surf! %nnick $+ 's turn.
        }
        else if (%co == 09) {
          %msg = %snick is hit by Energy Ball! %nnick $+ 's turn.
        }
        else if (%co == 08) {
          %msg = %snick is hit by Thunderbolt! %nnick $+ 's turn.
        }
        else {
          %msg = %snick is hit by Flamethrower! %nnick $+ 's turn.
        }
      }
      elseif (%c == [R]) {
        hadd # rev $iif($hget(#,rev),$false,$true)
        nextturn
        var %nnick = $hget(#,p $+ $hget(#,turn))
        if (%co == 08) {
          %msg = $nick used Volt Switch! %nnick $+ 's turn.
        }
        else
        {
          %msg = $nick used U Turn! %nnick $+ 's turn.
        }
      }
      elseif (%c == [*]) && (4 isin $2-) {
        nextturn
        var %snick = $hget(#,p $+ $hget(#,turn)), %nnick, %msg
        hadd # %snick $instok($hget(#,%snick),$cards(4),0,32)
        nextturn
        %nnick = $hget(#,p $+ $hget(#,turn))
        if (%co == 12) {
          %msg = %snick is hit by Hydro Cannon $+ $chr(44) and draws 4! %nnick $+ 's turn.
        }
        else if (%co == 09) {
          %msg = %snick is hit by Frenzy Plant $+ $chr(44) and draws 4! %nnick $+ 's turn.
        }
        else if (%co == 08) {
          %msg = %snick is hit by Bolt Strike $+ $chr(44) and draws 4! %nnick $+ 's turn.
        }
        else {
          %msg = %snick is hit by Blast Burn $+ $chr(44) and draws 4! %nnick $+ 's turn.
        }      }
      elseif (%c == [*]) {
        nextturn
        var %nnick = $hget(#,p $+ $hget(#,turn))
        if (%co == 12) {
          %msg = Deck Type is now Water! %nnick $+ 's turn.
        }
        else if (%co == 09) {
          %msg = Deck Type is now Grass! %nnick $+ 's turn.
        }
        else if (%co == 08) {
          %msg = Deck Type is now Electric! %nnick $+ 's turn.
        }
        else {
          %msg = Deck Type is now Fire! %nnick $+ 's turn.
        }
      }
      else {
        nextturn
        var %nnick = $hget(#,p $+ $hget(#,turn)), %msg = %nnick $+ 's turn.
      }
      if ($numtok($hget(#,$nick),32) == 1) msg # $nick has 3U04N12O!
      elseif (!$v1) {
        msg # Congratulations $nick - you won the match!!!
        hfree #
        hinc uno $nick
        return
      }
      msg # %msg
      msg # Top card: $hget(#,top)
      notice %nnick Your cards: $hget(#,%nnick)
      hdel # pass
    }
    else notice $nick That card doesn't play.
  }
}
alias cards {
  var %c = 12[1] 12[2] 12[3] 12[4] 12[5] 12[6] 12[7] 12[8] 12[9] 09[1] 09[2] 09[3] 09[4] 09[5] 09[6] 09[7] 09[8] 09[9] $&
    08[1] 08[2] 08[3] 08[4] 08[5] 08[6] 08[7] 08[8] 08[9] 04[1] 04[2] 04[3] 04[4] 04[5] 04[6] 04[7] 04[8] 04[9] 01[WD4] $&
    01[WD4] 01[WD4] 01[WD4] 12[D2] 12[D2] 09[D2] 09[D2] 08[D2] 08[D2] 04[D2] 04[D2] 12[S] 12[S] 09[S] 09[S] 08[S] 08[S] $&
    04[S] 04[S] 12[R] 12[R] 09[R] 09[R] 08[R] 08[R] 04[R] 04[R] 01[W] 01[W] 01[W] 01[W]
  var %i = $1, %o
  while (%i) { 
    %o = $instok(%o,$gettok(%c,$r(1,68),32),0,32)
    dec %i
  }
  return %o
}
alias iscard {
  if ($regex($1,/^([bgyr])\w* (\d)$/i)) return $+($col($regml(1)),[,$regml(2),])
  elseif ($regex($1,/^w(?:ild)? ?d?(?:raw)? ?4? ([bgyr])/i)) return $col($regml(1)) $+ [*]
  elseif ($regex($1,/^([bgyr])\w* d(?:raw)?2$/i)) return $col($regml(1)) $+ [D2]
  elseif ($regex($1,/^([bgyr])\w* ([sr])\w*$/i)) return $+($col($regml(1)),[,$upper($regml(2)),])
}
alias col {
  if ($1 == b) return 12
  elseif ($1 == g) return 09
  elseif ($1 == y) return 08
  else return 04
}
alias nextturn {
  var %c = $iif(#,#,$1)
  $iif($hget(%c,rev),hinc,hdec) %c turn
  if (!$hget(%c,p $+ $hget(%c,turn))) hadd %c turn $iif($hget(%c,rev),1,$hget(%c,players))
}
alias hascard {
  var %c = $iscard($1)
  if ($strip(%c) == [*]) {
    if (4 isin $1) return $istok($hget(#,$2),01[wd4],32)
    else return $istok($hget(#,$2),01[W],32)
  }
  else return $istok($hget(#,$2),%c,32)
}
alias delcard {
  var %c = $iscard($2-), %o
  if ($strip(%c) == [*]) %o = $iif(4 isin $2-,01[wd4],01[W])
  else %o = %c
  hadd # $1 $remtok($hget(#,$1),%o,1,32)
}
alias remplayer {
  var %p = $hfind($1,$2).data, %i = $right(%p,-1)
  hdel $1 $2
  hdel $1 %p
  hdec $1 players
  msg $1 $3-
  if ($hget($1,players) == 1) { 
    msg $1 Game ended, you need atleast two people to uno.
    hfree $1
  }
  else {
    if (!$hget($1,p $+ $hget($1,turn))) {
      if (!$hget($1,top)) return
      nextturn $1
      var %nnick = $hget($1,p $+ $hget($1,turn))
      msg $1 %nnick $+ 's turn.
      msg $1 Top card: $hget($1,top)
      notice %nnick Your cards: $hget($1,%nnick)
    }
    while (%i <= $hget($1,players)) {
      hadd $1 p $+ %i $hget($1,p $+ $calc(%i +1))
      hdel $1 p $+ $calc(%i +1)
      inc %i
    }
  }
}
```

I think I might have already found one of the problems regarding the skip notice not showing, but I'm not so sure about the other statements. What is it which I'm doing wrong here, and how can I correct it so that I can get the statements to show correctly?

Comment: Update: I've found out what the problem was with the 'Reverse' one, and fixed it, so all that's left is the color problem.

Comment: You can't tell statements like "I have problems" You need to explain exactly what is the problem, when it is happens and what you expected. Additionally must of the time you will not get help on 3rd party code only from the creators(if you will contact them.. and that also not for sure). Giving us bunch of code and expect us to fix it for you and guess the problems is insane, unrealistic and disrespectful. Give us more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the %co variable wasn't what I thought it would turn out to be. So what I did was temporally used a msg line at the end of the block where the problem was to figure out what %co came out as, and I noticed that the first two characters determined the color of the card. So, after using $left(%co,2) to get the two characters in %col, all I had to do was to check %col against the four color codes, and post the right info for that line.

I also, as a response to some people complaining about the color of the cards, slightly alter the colors, but I had done that before fully solving the problem of the wrong-showing cards.

Here is the segment of code which I had needed fixed, but is now fully fixed:

```
on $*:text:/^[~]play/Si:#:{
  if (!$hget(#,p1)) return
  elseif (!$hget(#,$nick)) notice $nick You aren't in this game.
  elseif ($hget(#,p $+ $hget(#,turn)) != $nick) notice $nick It is not your turn.
  elseif (!$iscard($2-)) notice $nick Syntax: ~play <color>/<type> <card> or ~play WD4/W <color>/<type>
  elseif (!$hascard($2-,$nick)) notice $nick You don't have that card.
  else {
    noop $regex($iscard($2-),/^\x03(\d{2})(\[.+?\])$/)
    var %co = $regml(1), %c = $regml(2)
    if (%co isin $hget(#,top)) || (%c == $strip($hget(#,top))) || (%c == [*]) {
      delcard $nick $2-
      hadd # top $iscard($2-)
      var %col = $left(%co,2)
      if (%c == [D2]) {
        nextturn
        var %snick = $hget(#,p $+ $hget(#,turn)), %nnick, %msg
        hadd # %snick $instok($hget(#,%snick),$cards(2),0,32)
        nextturn
        %nnick = $hget(#,p $+ $hget(#,turn))
        if (%col == 12) {
          %msg = %snick is hit by Hydro Pump $+ $chr(44) and draws 2! %nnick $+ 's turn.
        }
        else if (%col == 03) {
          %msg = %snick is hit by Seed Flare $+ $chr(44) and draws 2! %nnick $+ 's turn.
        }
        else if (%col == 07) {
          %msg = %snick is hit by Thunder $+ $chr(44) and draws 2! %nnick $+ 's turn.
        }
        else {
          %msg = %snick is hit by Fire Blast $+ $chr(44) and draws 2! %nnick $+ 's turn.
        }
      }
      elseif (%c == [S]) {
        nextturn
        var %snick = $hget(#,p $+ $hget(#,turn)), %nnick, %msg
        nextturn
        %nnick = $hget(#,p $+ $hget(#,turn))
        %msg = %snick is hit by Fake Out! %nnick $+ 's turn.
      }
      elseif (%c == [R]) {
        hadd # rev $iif($hget(#,rev),$false,$true)
        var %unick = $hget(#,p $+ $hget(#,turn))
        nextturn
        var %nnick = $hget(#,p $+ $hget(#,turn))
        %msg = %unick used U Turn! %nnick $+ 's turn.
      }
      elseif (%c == [*]) && (4 isin $2-) {
        nextturn
        var %snick = $hget(#,p $+ $hget(#,turn)), %nnick, %msg
        hadd # %snick $instok($hget(#,%snick),$cards(4),0,32)
        nextturn
        %nnick = $hget(#,p $+ $hget(#,turn))
        %msg = %snick is hit by Judgement $+ $chr(44) and draws 4! %nnick $+ 's turn.
      }
      elseif (%c == [*]) {
        nextturn
        var %nnick = $hget(#,p $+ $hget(#,turn))
        if (%col == 12) {
          %msg = Deck Type is now Water! %nnick $+ 's turn.
        }
        else if (%col == 03) {
          %msg = Deck Type is now Grass! %nnick $+ 's turn.
        }
        else if (%col == 07) {
          %msg = Deck Type is now Electric! %nnick $+ 's turn.
        }
        else {
          %msg = Deck Type is now Fire! %nnick $+ 's turn.
        }
      }
      else {
        nextturn
        var %nnick = $hget(#,p $+ $hget(#,turn)), %msg = %nnick $+ 's turn.
      }
      if ($numtok($hget(#,$nick),32) == 1) msg # $nick has 3U04N12O!
      elseif (!$v1) {
        msg # Congratulations $nick - you won the match!!!
        hfree #
        hinc uno $nick
        return
      }
      msg # %msg
      msg # Top card: $hget(#,top)
      notice %nnick Your cards: $hget(#,%nnick)
      hdel # pass
    }
    else notice $nick That card doesn't play.
  }
}
alias cards {
  var %c = 12[1] 12[2] 12[3] 12[4] 12[5] 12[6] 12[7] 12[8] 12[9] 03[1] 03[2] 03[3] 03[4] 03[5] 03[6] 03[7] 03[8] 03[9] $&
    07[1] 07[2] 07[3] 07[4] 07[5] 07[6] 07[7] 07[8] 07[9] 04[1] 04[2] 04[3] 04[4] 04[5] 04[6] 04[7] 04[8] 04[9] 01[WD4] $&
    01[WD4] 01[WD4] 01[WD4] 12[D2] 12[D2] 03[D2] 03[D2] 07[D2] 07[D2] 04[D2] 04[D2] 12[S] 12[S] 03[S] 03[S] 07[S] 07[S] $&
    04[S] 04[S] 12[R] 12[R] 03[R] 03[R] 07[R] 07[R] 04[R] 04[R] 01[W] 01[W] 01[W] 01[W]
  var %i = $1, %o
  while (%i) { 
    %o = $instok(%o,$gettok(%c,$r(1,68),32),0,32)
    dec %i
  }
  return %o
}
```